# Using XPath and Selenium with arbitrary document element as root

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dom, xpath

A nice feature of Selenium is that the scope of `find_elements()` and related methods can be restricted to any node within the document. For example,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'chromedriver.exe')

driver.get("https://www.wikipedia.org/")
driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "div")
```

will return all `div` elements in the document, but

```
footerElement = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "footer")
footerElement.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "div")
```

will return only those `div` elements in the footer. Is there a way to get similar functionality when finding elements with `By.XPATH`? I ask because `footerElement.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div")` returns all `div` elements in the document -- not just those in the footer, which is what I would like it to do.

To be clear: I know how to construct an XPath statement to get only the `div` elements in the footer. But I want to know whether it is possible to start with any arbitrary node, like `footerElement` in the example above, and then use very simple syntax like `footerElement.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div")` to get only those `div` elements that are in the footer.

Comment: It's not ideal, but you could always write `"//footer//div"`.

Comment: Thank you, @AMC. That is close, though I think that particular approach will work only for elements whose tag name is `footer`.

Comment: I'm confused.. Is `footer` the class of the element, or the element?

Comment: Thank you for alerting me to the potential for confusion. The answer is: `footer` is the class of an element at https://www.wikipedia.org. In the original version of my post, it was also an object of the WebElement type; this object was created by `footer = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "footer")`. But to prevent confusion, I've renamed this object from `footer` to `footerElement`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can find only those divs in the footer by using `footer.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//div")`.

Comment: I believe `"//div"` should suffice.

Comment: That's what I thought, too. But it doesn't suffice -- see the "I ask because..." sentence in my post.

Comment: Sorry if my comment was ambiguous, I meant that you could use `"//div"` instead of `".//div"`, like `footer.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div")`.

Comment: I understood. But the problem is that `footer.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div")` matches all `div` elements in the entire document -- not just those that nest in the footer element.

Comment: Oh, my mistake, my assumption was that since you're calling the method on the footer element it would be restricted to everything under that element, and not the entire document.